# How to give each thread its own copy of some data

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, state

At the moment my code is using the same `ArrayList` to make a decision on where to move each object. But i want to give each thread its own `ArrayList` and for each thread to populate itself based on the `object` it is passed.

I have tried to `synchronize` the method which populates the `ArrayList` but this does not solve my problem.

```
for(Object o : s.objects) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        locations = s.getLocation(o.curLoc(), o.moves);
        location nextLoc;
        nextLoc = o.chooseBestLoc(locations);
        o.setLocation(nextLoc);
    }.start();
}
```

At the moment i think this should create a new `ArrayList` for each thread but the behavior of where my objects are moving is incorrect. They are moving to seemingly random locations.

How do i give each thread its own `ArrayList`? or make it so they can not share the same `ArrayList`?

Comment: `locations = s.getLocation(o.curLoc(), o.moves);` ***replaces*** the value of `locations`, so the initialization done in `ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>()` is **discarded**. Remove the initialization, as it is a waste of resources. Then either fix the `getLocation()` method to return a new list, or take a copy of the returned list: `locations = new ArrayList<>(s.getLocation(o.curLoc(), o.moves));`

Answer (score 0):

So what u can do:

1. Create your own class which extends Thread, with arrayList as class field
2. Add object parameter to constructor
3. In the new constructor populate arrayList bases on the object passed

   ```
   class MyThread extends Thread {

     private List<Location> locations;

     public MyThread(Object o) {
        locations = .... // do somth to convert object to arraylist
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Ehrebeco, I think using two deep copies of the list. One for looping and one within the thread. Hope this helps.

Regards, Srikanth Kondaveti